# How to know if contents are shared successfully using ACTION_SEND?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have used the following codes to share my contents in other apps:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, st);
    String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getActivity().getContentResolver(), bmp, "", null);
    Uri screenshotUri = Uri.parse(path);

    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, screenshotUri);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share"));
```

I know need to know if the share is complete or not, and if possible in which application has the user shared my content. How can I do this?

Comment: `startActivityForResult`?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with Intent.

[ACTION_SEND](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEND) is not designed to work with `startActivityForResult()`;

`ACTION_SEND` does NOT have any output as a result you always get the default value which is `RESULT_CANCELED`.

Also you can NOT check it with Intent data coming back because it is always null or 0.